# String comparison in onPostexecute not working

Tags: java, android

Following code is what I added for intent and result is something that is returned from my login.php. But it fails to compare if it is success or not. It does not enter the if loop in any case. It shows "Login Success" in the alert dialog though.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result.equals("Login Success")){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("com.example.soumya.attendance","com.example.soumya.attendance.LoginActivity");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);}
            else{
                alertDialog.setMessage("No Condition Matched..");
                alertDialog.show();
            }

    }
```

Login.php

```
<?php  
 require "init.php";  
 $uname = $_POST["login_name"];  
 $password =  $_POST["login_pass"];  
 $sql_query = "select name from students where uname like '$uname' and password like '$password';";  
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0 )  
 {  
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
 $name =$row["name"];  
 echo "Login Success";  
 }  
 else  
 {   
 echo "Login Failed.......Try Again..";  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: post the complete async task and also post exact response being returned by login api.

Comment: Why dont you use the debugger to see the value of the string, so you know whats happening.

Comment: How could `result`ever be `Registration Success...` when your PHP code never returns such text as the response?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen yes that what I told him

Comment: I removed the if condition. That is not the problem. I will update the question in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
result.contains("Login Success"){ // contains will check the availability of Login Success.
//Your Code
}
```

instead of

```
if(result.equals("Login Success")){  // check the Complete String .
  //Your Code
}
```

Comment: what a misluck, i answered first and your answer is accepted :-D

Answer (score 3):

try using `result.contains("Login Success")` instead of `result.equals()` as PHP my return some symbols in the end like server-specific carriage return or so.

Comment: I have tried two times for the answer man but each time he change his question.. after final revision i get succeeded..  But still I never complain.


Champs never complain. Does a up-vote for your answer. Keep trying you will get success man. don't feel embrace yourself and keep trying Champ..

Comment: I am really sorry. I refreshed the page after some time and since he had answered twice, I got his answer on the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check "Login Success" instead of "Registration Success..."

And also use boolean value for return type at PHP side.
like status true/false.

Don't use string as status.

At PHP side:

```
echo true;  
else
echo false;
```

Like that.

At Android side:

```
if(result)
{
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: how do i return a boolean type of status from php and check here?

Comment: But onPostExecute takes in only string as an argument,:(

Comment: then just use if(result.equals("Login Success")) instead of if(result.equals("Registration Success...")) which I told you before

Comment: because in your PHP file nothing like "Registration Success..." :(